# Long click doesn't work with ListView

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set long-click listener for ListView:

```
final ListView gallery=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.dialogViewImagesList);
gallery.setLongClickable(true);
gallery.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
        Log.e("event", "long");
        return true;
    }

});
gallery.setAdapter(new PointImagesAdapter(bitmaps));
```

It's my adapter:

```
private class PointImagesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bitmap> {

    private static final int LAYOUT_ID=R.layout.adapter_point_images;
    private List<Bitmap> bitmaps;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public PointImagesAdapter(List<Bitmap> bitmaps) {
        super(MainActivity.this, LAYOUT_ID, bitmaps);
        this.bitmaps=bitmaps;
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup group) {
        if (view==null) {
            view=inflater.inflate(LAYOUT_ID, null);
        }

        ImageView i=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.adapterPointImagesItem);
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        i.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(position));

        view.setFocusable(false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I've tried set view.setLongClickable(true), but in this case ListView items are not clickable (simple click doesn't work). It's layout code for adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:id="@+id/adapterPointImagesItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't understand why this code doesn't work! How can I fix it?

Comment: Use setOnItemLongClickListener: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemLongClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener)

Comment: @user2218845 is it working or not?

Answer (score 13):

You have to use `setOnItemLongClickListener`

```
gallery.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            final int arg2, long arg3) {

    });
}
```

Also, If your listview's adapter extends from BaseAdapter, then you also need to set `convertView.setLongClickable(true);` in the `getView()`.